# How to use this library in python "from digidevice import location"?

Tags: geolocation, location, coordinates

How can I get coordinates from user's device, using this library in python: "from digidevice import location".
I tried, but cant even import this library.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [link](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90002381/os/python-digidevice-location-c.htm?TocPath=Applications%7CDigidevice%20module%7CUse%20Python%20to%20access%20the%20device%20location%20data%7C_____0)

It seems like this will work:

```
from digidevice import location
loc = location.Location()
print(loc.position)
```

Comment: python dont recognise digidevice library..

Comment: Did you download the package? Where did you find the package?